# SQL change a string using a pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to do something special in SQL, I don't know if a standard function exists, I actually don't know what to search... ! So any advice would be appreciated.

**Here is my problem:**

I have a data which is a number: `7000000`
And I have a "formatting pattern": `****5**`

My goal is to merge both: result for this example is: `7000500`
(a star means to keep the original value, and a number means to change it)

another example:

```
7894321
*0**9*1
-------
7094921
```

(I use SQL Server)

Comment: If I understand this correctly: You search for a function that replaces particular characters in a string depending on a formatting pattern? In a way a tally table with character comparison and output replacement comes to my mind. Not afaik a standard function.

Comment: I was going to answer: use `FORMAT(MyNumber, '0000\500')` but it doesn't work because it adds in an extra digit. You're best off doing some arithmetic if you've got just numbers to format

Comment: @Charlieface, i confirm that I have only numbers. What kind of arithmetic would you think about ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task can be performed in any programming language with basic `for-loop` and and some internal functions to find *substring* and *replace*

Here is how it's done in SQL SERVER (*given that the string and the format is of same length*)

1. Create your own function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Formatter
(
    @str NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @format NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @i int = 1, @len int = LEN(@str)

    -- Iterates over over each char in the FORMAT and replace the original string if applies
    WHILE @i <= @len
    BEGIN
        IF SUBSTRING(@format, @i, 1) <> '*'
            SET @str = STUFF(@str, @i, 1, SUBSTRING(@format, @i, 1))

        SET @i = @i + 1
    END

    RETURN @str
END
```

2. USE your function in your SELECTs, e.g.

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(MAX) = '7894321'
DECLARE @format VARCHAR(MAX) = '*0**9*1'

PRINT('Format: ' + @format)
PRINT('Old string: ' + @str)

PRINT('New string: ' + dbo.Formatter(@str, @format))
```

Result:

```
Format: *0**9*1
Old string: 7894321
New string: 7094921
```

Comment: This is a very rare instance where I think a user-defined function might be the most reasonable approach.

Comment: thank you it's very clear, i like it, I was hoping a standard function but if it doesn't exists i will use yours

Answer (score 0):

I would split the string into it's individual characters, use a `CASE` expression to determine what character should be retained, and then remerge. I'm going to *assume* you're on a recent version of SQL Server, and thus have access to `STRING_AGG`; if not, you'll want to use the "old" `FOR XML PATH` method. I also assume a string of length 10 of less (if it's more, then just increase the size of the tally).

```sql
DECLARE @Format varchar(10) = '****5**';

WITH Tally AS(
    SELECT V.I
    FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10))V(I))
SELECT STRING_AGG(CASE SSf.C WHEN '*' THEN SSc.C ELSE SSf.C END,'') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY T.I) AS NewString
FROM (VALUES(1,'7894321'),(2,'7000000'))YT(SomeID,YourColumn) --This would be your table
     JOIN Tally T ON LEN(YT.YourColumn) >= T.I
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(YT.YourColumn,T.I,1)))SSc(C)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(@Format,T.I,1)))SSf(C)
GROUP BY YT.SomeID;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=73f467c70cb73c795432cb845e8de84d)

Answer (score 0):

If your value is an `int` and your format is an `int` also, then you can do this:

```sql
DECLARE @formatNum int = CAST(REPLACE(@format, '*', '0') AS int);

SELECT f.Formatted
FROM Table
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT Formatted = SUM(CASE
        WHEN ((@FormatNum / Base) % 10) > 0
        THEN ((@FormatNum / Base) % 10) * Base
        ELSE ((t.MyNumber / Base) % 10) * Base END
    FROM (VALUES
        (10),(100),(1000),(10000),(100000),(1000000),(10000000),(100000000),(1000000000)
    ) v(Base)
) f
```

The `/` is integer division, `%` is modulo, so dividing a number by `Base` and taking the modulo 10 will give you exactly one digit.